# Atomic compare and swap in assembler OS independent

Tags: c, linux, windows, assembly, atomic

I am writing OS independent lockless queue, queue works fine (with default windows\linux atomic CAS), but I want to make queue work without any change in linux and windows. So I gues I should write my own CAS in assembler, or there is other ways to achieveit ?

So far I have this code:

```
global _CAS

_CAS:

    mov eax, [esp+4]    
    mov edx, [esp+8]    
    mov ecx, [esp+12]   

    ;XCHG eax, edx  <- this function works fine
     CMPXCHG  ecx, eax, ebx 

    ret
```

I know that I still have to add `lock` before `CMPXCHG` and it should work with structures, but for now I'm more interested in making it working.

I compile using nasm-2.10.05 with this command `nasm.exe -f elf -o cas.o  cas.asm`
and I get this error `testas\cas.asm:14: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`

Comment: This approach limits you to the x86 platform.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With C11 or newer, you should be using `<stdatomic.h>`, which has broad support these days:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>
```

See [atomic_compare_exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange). I won't try and summarize the exact semantics here.

Without C11, you can do it with intrinsics on both platforms, no need for assembly:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
# include <intrin.h>
# define CAS(ptr, oldval, newval) \
    _InterlockedCompareExchange(ptr, newval, oldval)
#elif __GNUC__
# if __GNUC__ < 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 1)
#  error "requires GCC 4.1 or greater"
# endif
# define CAS(ptr, oldval, newval) \
    __sync_val_compare_and_swap(ptr, oldval, newval)
#else
# error "CAS not supported on this platform"
#endif
```

Both of these support the following interface:

```
/* If the current value of *ptr is oldval, then write newval
   into *ptr.  Returns the initial value of *ptr.  */
long CAS(long *ptr, long oldval, long newval);
```

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttk2z1ws(v=vs.100).aspx), [GCC documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins).  This should also work on Clang with no modification, since Clang advertises `__GNUC__` compatibility with its predefined macros.

Comment: This might do the thing, how about Mac OS ? Will it need extra #ifdef ?

Comment: @Full_Int: It works on OS X.  Make sure you don't use GCC 4.0 on OS X.

Comment: if not supported,any methods to do the same thing？

Comment: @52Coder: what platform and tool chain are you using?

Comment: @52coder: `<stdatomic.h>` for `atomic_compare_exchange_weak` since ISO C11.  If it's supported as `lock_free` on your C11 implementation, it should be using `lock cmpxchg`.  (Any realistic C implementation should do that.)

Answer (score 5):

According to http://web.itu.edu.tr/kesgin/mul06/intel/instr/cmpxchg.html, `cmpxchg` takes two, not three parameters.

Maybe, http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h is of interest too.